# How to determine screen orientation and size bucket programatically in Android 2.3.3 SDK

Tags: android, screen-orientation

My application is supposed decide whether to display in dual-pane or single-pane using the following logic:

1. For ALL screen sizes, if in portrait display in SINGLE-PANE
2. For SMALL and NORMAL screen sizes, if in landscape display in SINGLE-PANE
3. For LARGE and XLARGE screen sizes, if in landscape display in DUAL-PANE

I am developing for Android 2.3.3 SDK, so the nice features of Android 3.0 SDK are not applicable here. The function I have developed below always returns SINGLE-PANE for all screen sizes and orientation combinations. What could be going wrong here?

```
/**
 * Determine if a dual pane is appropriate.
 * 
 * @param null
 * @return boolean
 */

public boolean isDualPane() {

    boolean dualPane    = false;

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

            dualPane    = true;
        }
    }

    Log.d("ORIANTATION", (dualPane) ? "DUAL PANE" : "SINGLE PANE");

    return dualPane;
}
```

Comment: what size of your 2.3 devices' resolution ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer. **There is nothing wrong with the above function!** The problem was with the configuration of my emulator. I created a WVGA800 device and left the LCD density at 240 instead of 160. That makes it a normal size and not a large size. So the statememnt `Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE` always evaluated to 2 instead of 3. So the `if statement` failed each time. It works fine now.

One more thing, **this**:

```
        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout 
           & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

            dualPane    = true;
        }
```

needs to  be **changed to:**

```
        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout 
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

            dualPane    = true;
        }
```

In order to cater for XLARGE screens as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about dual pane, but I suggest you control the configuration Small-Normal-Large-Xlarge layout from XML.

Example :

1. All screen size -  portrait. it takes the default layout folder :  ***res/layout***
2. Small screen size -  landscape :  ***res/layout-small-land***
3. Large Xlarge screen size -  landscape : ***res/layout-large-land***

It maybe Helping you. :)

Refference : [Screen size](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that part `/res/layout-...` is already in place. I need that info to do other decisions in the code.